# Method of evaluating shellcode in python?

Tags: python, c, security, shellcode

Evaluating a sample piece of shellcode using a C program is not complicated. It would involve storing the shellcode in a character array, creating a function pointer, typecasting the pointer and making it point to the array and calling the function(pointer).

This is how it works, assuming you can execute the memory at `nastycode[]`:

```
/* left harmless. Insert your own working example at your peril */
char nastycode[] = "\x00\x00\x00...";
void (*execute_ptr) (void);

execute_ptr = (void *)nastycode; /* point pointer at nasty code */
execute_ptr();                   /* execute it */
```

Is there any way I could do the same using Python code? Or does the fact that Python code translates to bytecode render such an endeavour impossible?

Comment: Actually, even the C method that you propose is going to work less and less on modern platforms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit

Comment: Can you reference an example of doing what you are describing (evaluating shellcode using a C program)?  It would help make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: All you need to do to bypass NX is to allocate a read/write/execute page.  On Windows you would use PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE when calling VirtualAlloc.  NX only helps when the code can't perform an alloc like this.

Comment: @pyrony it's fairly straightfoward, I've edited the question to show you (and others) how it happens. @zubin71 I've changed your title to be more descriptive; if you don't like it, or wish to change what I've edited, feel free!

Comment: This doesn't necessarily work in "C". Pointers to code and data might occupy entirely different address spaces.

Comment: But how is any of this a problem in Python? You can simply do `exec nastycode`.

Comment: @Conrad yes, then they'd be different processes. This is an example of how to deliberately execute some shellcode in your program (i.e. as a test), not how to actually exploit an application to get it working.

Comment: @Ninefingers Not what I meant. You can't necessarily assign a data pointer to a function pointer, and vice versa. They may refer to different memories entirely, on (for example) a Harvard architecture. (The fact that you *can* do this on x86, and GCC supports it as an extension, doesn't make it allowed in ISO C99.)

Comment: @Conrad Ahh, right, yes of course. Some of us don't venture much beyond x86... Indeed, on such architectures you couldn't use this technique at all; but since it's only a method of testing such execution, you simply find another way to do it. MSVC also supports this I *think* (and even if it doesn't, there's mingw), so that gives you this technique on most major platforms... in any case since that's what the OP is describing, we can assume he's using it on platforms/toolchains that do support it. But yes, I'm sorry, you are technically correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way this could be done is if you rely on a C library.  Buffer overflows can be introduced into python from its library bindings.  For your purposes you could write your own simple python library in c and implement something like example3.c in [Aleph One's Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html).  As Avilo pointed out you will have to worry about NX zones,  however any region of memory can be made executable again and this is platform specific. Also GCC uses stack canaries by default.  Although this can be avoided by just overwriting the return address with an address passed to the function,  which would leave the cannery intact.  ASLR is a very good security system that can be difficult to bypass,  but if you are passing in the known address to your shell code then ASLR shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: note in exploitation, ASLR is not problem if we can brute it directly ;) .

Comment: @Gunslinger_  that is the idea behind heap spraying.  If you have a large enough block of memory to jmp to then it you can still find it even if pages are randomized.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for ;)

http://libemu.carnivore.it/

Since you where looking for python:

https://github.com/buffer/pylibemu

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in python... you can do your own binding to C using ctypes or simply use something like distorm

http://code.google.com/p/distorm/wiki/Python

you also might want to check out how dionaea does it. Its a honeypot but it'll test shellcode and output the results.

http://dionaea.carnivore.it/